# I get funny characters when reading multipart and text messages using Zend Mail?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, character-encoding, zend-mail

Hi guys I've shifted to using the zend framework for reading messages from an inbox however when reading some html messages I see a lot of weird charcters like:

```
don’t
```

looks like

```
don=92t
```

Plus other weird characters like =20 .. whats going on? Is it an ecoding issue? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [quoted-printable encoding](http://ask-leo.com/why_does_my_email_sometimes_show_up_with_funny_characters_like_0d_in_it.html): You'll need to [decode the quoted-printable string](http://documentation.kpwebstudio.co.uk/Zend_Mime/Zend_Mime_Decode.html).

Comment: WOW! Thats spot on - but how can I set it up to detect whether its a quoted printable string BEFORE decoding? Or would running a decode quoted printable on any string have no effect unless it is quoted printable?

Comment: You should be able to check the `content-transfer-encoding` to see if it's quoted-printable, but I'm not sure how to do that in Zend 
off the top of my head.

As for just decoding strings: If the string contains a quoted-printable sequence (such as `=92`), but it isn't actually quoted-printable (the sender actually wants you to see '=92'), then you'd have a problem, otherwise you'd be fine.